# How to convert OLE Automation span to TimeSpan or seconds?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have time span in OLE automation `double` units. I would like to convert it into seconds or `TimeSpan` object. I searched for related functions in `TimeSpan` or `DateTime` classes, but couldn't find any.

Comment: I daresay you [didn't look very hard](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I looked into that, but I don't need date/time. I need time span.

Comment: Then subtract `DateTime.FromOADate(0)`. (Technically `TimeSpan.FromDays` should also do, since that's what an automation date *is*, but I'd consider that less clear -- `FromOADate` makes it clear what the origins are.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a OLE Automation date for the start and end-dates you should be able to convert it to a timespan by just calling [DateTime.FromOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-fromoadate(system-double)) and taking the difference between the two values.

If you only have one value it sounds like someone is misusing the data type to represent a timespan instead of a date. I'm not familiar with OLE Automation, but the documentation states:

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24.

So I would assume that you should just be able to call [TimeSpan.FromDays(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromdays?view=net-6.0) to produce a timespan.

Once you have a timespan you can just use the `TotalSeconds` property if you want seconds.